# Java Stream Filter issue comparing a streamed value to all list value

Tags: java, backend

[Here is a pic because newbie to Stackoverflow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/emO5Q.png)

I'm needing some help on a little issue i'm having rn.

private

My problem is on this line

private

The list is filled with some id's that are "whitelisted" and i'd like to compare the current's id (streamed) to all the value of the list. And only if the value match with one of the list ID, let it go to the next step.
Thx for help.

Comment: I see some red underneath the .get method of the quizList. If it's a list, you cannot get without an index.

Comment: convert the ids in the list into a set first and then check membership in the set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `quizList` is Java collection then it does not have `get` method. In your filter to check if `current.getId()` exists in `quizList` you can use streams to do that

```
.filter(current -> quizList.stream()
    .anyMatch( quiz -> Objects.equals( current.getId(), quiz.getId() ) ) )
```

Answer (score 2):

Doing a sequential search of `quizList`, for every Quiz object with the given category, is bad for performance.

You should convert `quizList` into a `Set` for faster lookup.

```
Set<Integer> quizIds = quizList.stream()
  .map(Quiz::getId)
  .collect(Collectors.toSet());

return hibernateQuizJpaRepository.findAllByCategorySetContaining(new HibernateQuizCategory(quizCategoryId))
  .stream()
  .filter(current -> quizIds.contains(current.getId()))
  // ...
```

Comment: I agree. The accepted answer looks nicer, but sucks in terms of performance.

Answer (score -1):

Please stop use streams everywhere

```
.filter(quizList::contains)
```

Comment: That won't be comparing the `id` fields.

Comment: @Andreas Don't you specify equals/hashCode methods for Quiz class?

Comment: *I* don't do anything, since I'm not the questioner. *If* the class implements `equals` to compare `id` only (not all the other fields too, which is usually the case when implementing `equals`), then your answer would work, but that is an **unstated assumption** in your answer. Could be a valid assumption, but I doubt it, since the code in the question was specifically written to compare `id` values.